# Identify Current view controller from PopUp view controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Assume that we have 2 view controllers

1. FirstViewController.swift
2. PopUpViewContraller.swift

PopUpViewContraller has been loaded on FirstViewController. Now how can I call a function in the FirstViewController from PopUpViewContraller.

Comment: you can achieve this by either Observer or @procol(custom delegate)

Comment: Delegates are very useful here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for answer my question.

Finally, I got the solution for the above question.

We can solve this problem using notification center.

1) In the popup view controller ()

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "botIsRemoved"), object: self)
```

2) In the first view controller

inside viewDidLoard()

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(removeBotNow), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "botIsRemoved"), object: nil)
```

and add the following function

```
@objc func removeBotNow(notification : Notification){

        // your tasks

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Native Swift Protocols:

```
protocol masterGreeting {
    func sayHi()
}

class FirstVC: UIViewController, masterGreeting {
      func sayHi() {
        print("Hi")
      }


    // When you present PopUpViewController
    func displaySecondVC() {
       let vc = secondController()
       vc.delegate = self
       self.present(vc, animated: true)
    }

}
```

In your PopUpViewController:

```
class PopUpViewController: UIViewController {
    var delegate: masterGreeting?

     self.delegate?.sayHi() // Say HI


}
```

Theres more to find about `Protocols` here:

[Protocols — The Swift Programming Language (Swift 5) - Swift.org](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html)

Comment: use a weak delegate to be safe. he doesn't need to strongly retain in this scenario

Comment: @JoshuaFrancisRoman In the end, I don't know how this code will be used, therefore the op has to make several changes.

Comment: Be aware of retain cycle in your code. Make the reference for `delegate` to be weak, therefore declare `masterGreeting` protocol as: `protocol masterGreeting: AnyObject`.

Comment: @AhmadF. Contributions are welcome. Please make an edit. I don't want to take credit for your code

Answer (score 0):

**Another approach:**

Use **`closures`** to get that working. **Apple** has used `closures` extensively in `Swift`.

1. Create the `closure` variable in `PopUpViewContraller`
2. Set the `closure` from `FirstViewController` when `PopUpViewContraller` is presented.
3. Call the `closure` when `PopUpViewContraller` is dismissed.

**Example:**

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func openPopupVC(_ sender: Any) {
        if let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopUpViewContraller") as? PopUpViewContraller {
            controller.handler = {[weak self] in
                self?.callFromHandler()
            }
            self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    
    func callFromHandler() {
        print("Working..!!!")
    }
}

class PopUpViewContraller: UIViewController {
    var handler: (()->())?
    
    @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true) {
            self.handler?()
        }
    }
}
```

**Delegates** ofcourse is another way of doing that. You can follow any one of the approaches.